# Simple Hello Android.....not workign

Tags: android

**EDIT: SOLVED I JUST HAD TO WAIT FOR AWHILE**

So I followed the simple "Hello Android" tutorial:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html

got everything set up fine.....stuff works but when I go to actually run it.....it just says "Android_" in my virtual device....

I tried running it on 2.1 2.2 2.3.1 and 2.3.3 VD's and get the same thing?

```
package com.example.helloandroid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       TextView tv = new TextView(this);
       tv.setText("Hello, Android");
       setContentView(tv);
   }
}
```

Any ideas? My first venture into android is a failing one ;_;

PIC:
[image: Fails]

bigger:http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v720/bmw_pyro/Untitled-2.png

MANIFEST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.helloandroid"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".HelloAndroid"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: can you please specify where exactly you are getting the error? please explain

Comment: have you wait a moment ? The emulator could take long time to display app.

Comment: I did explain the error. all it says is Android_, here ill upload a picture screenshot

Comment: Good catch Nanis....@Sauron please wait when android loads the Activity..there is nothing related to code here just matter of patience :)

Comment: Ya I might need to wait a min or something. ill try that.

Comment: Ok.....it worked.....just had to wait like 4 minutes lol. sorry <_<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Android _" is the first loading emulator splash screen, so you are saying that you get stuck there? If that's  the case, that has nothing to do with your code.